# delete large data folder from git history

Tags: git

I am trying to remove a folder called "GIS" containing large data files from my git history. I pushed this folder a couple of commits ago so an `--amend` won't work. Here's the command I'm trying:

`git filter-branch --tree-filter 'git rm -r --cached -- GIS/**' HEAD`

This throws an error:

```
fatal: bad revision 'rm'
```

Why does this error occur? How can I delete this folder from my `git` history?

Comment: How about `rm -rf GIS` instead of `git rm`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+remove+large+file+history

Comment: `git filter-branch --prune-empty --index-filter "git rm -rf --cached --ignore-unmatch GIS" -- --all`